# Hide Input Field and Still Take User Input

Tags: javascript, html, input, focus, hide

I was working on a project that I need a hidden input field to take user input.

I have javascript in place to focus always on the input field. When the div is visible I can see typing. When I hide the div type and make the div visible again I do not see any change. How can I make it so when the div is hidden, it will still take user input? Really, if there is another way besides hiding, that would be great.

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="diva">
<input name="geta" id="geta" type="text" onkeypress="javascript:geta.focus();" onKeyUp="javascript:geta.focus();" OnBlur="javascript:geta.focus();" OnChange="javascript:geta.focus();" />
</div>
<button onClick="javascript:change();">Show/Hide Div</button>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
 function change() {
    var div = document.getElementById('diva');
    if (div.style.display !== 'none') {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        div.style.display = 'block';
    }
};
geta.focus();
// -->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Fixed copy using Jeffman's idea:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
input {
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input name="geta" id="geta" type="text" onkeypress="javascript:geta.focus();" onKeyUp="javascript:geta.focus();" OnBlur="javascript:geta.focus();" OnChange="javascript:geta.focus();" />
<button onClick="javascript:show();">Show</button><button onClick="javascript:hide();">Hide</button>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
 function hide() {
        document.getElementById('geta').style.position = 'absolute';
        document.getElementById('geta').style.left = '-999em';
    }
 function show() {
        document.getElementById('geta').style.position = 'absolute';
        document.getElementById('geta').style.left = '10em';
    }
geta.focus();
// -->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe i've missed something, but it isn't clear what you want to achieve. Rather than telling us what you've implemented, tell us what you are trying to achieve because my guess is you're going about it in the wrong way

Comment: Try positioning the input so it is behind something else, like an image or something. OR try positioning it with negative coordinates so it's out of the viewport.

Comment: Thank you Jeffman. Your idea worked without a hitch. I posted a fixed copy for others to try if they wanted to see.

Answer (score 1):

Are you just trying to make it so any user input is captured to a hidden input field?

If so you can add a onkeyup trigger to the document, and for every keyup, modify the hidden input field.

Otherwise, once you have hidden an element it would loses focus.

Simple example:

I don't know if you are using jQuery, so here is a very native, simple solution, put in your head  tag

```
document.onkeyup = function(e) {
    var input = document.getElementById('myinput');
    if (input.style.display == 'none') {
        input.value += String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode || e.which);
    }
};
```

Comment: I like this method. If the input is hidden however, where would I have to put the onKeyUp trigger where the user can see it without looking at the source?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to type in a text field when it's hidden. What is your use case?

Comment: I need to capture a users input where if a certain series of keys are pressed it would fire a javascript function without using JQuery.

Comment: In that case try binding the keypresses to the `document` object.